# float element has top margin

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've floated an element right and for some reason it has a margin on top. I don't know where it's coming from.

HTML:

```
<p>...</p>
<p class="foo">...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.foo { 
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
}
```

Image:

[image: The image in which the <p> has a top margin]

codepen.io: http://codepen.io/vbelenky/pen/oEmHt

Comment: you have multiple duplicate answers below all of which are correct. You should accept the oldest answer :).

Comment: @Chandranshu These answers aren't "duplicates" from each other. Yours for example will set to 0 margins on ALL `p` elements even though only one element needed it, without explaining how to set back margins on all but one `p` (and without explaining why: where it came from in the first place)

Comment: @FelipeAls - Thanks for citing the standards! On the other hand, my solution asks him to add the style rule to **his CSS** which uses `p.foo`. So, it won't reset it on all `p` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style of `margin-top: 0px;` to your CSS. Browsers add 1em space before and after each paragraph. If you inspect the styles in Chrome and look for user-agent styles, you'll notice the following:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

The -webkit-margin-before is what is assigning that space on top of the floated paragraph. Also have a look at the following answer to understand how to develop your website in a cross-browser way:

- [Best Practice for CSS Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/best-practice-for-css-reset-style-sheet)

Comment: Yep Eric Meyer's reset css is probably the best, use it all the time, but through a plugin so I couldn't remember the author.

Comment: Default `p { margin: 1em 0 }` is as cross-browser as one can imagine. Once you've removed margins from ALL your `p` elements (that's what E. Meyer reset does), what do you do to separate vertically other paragraphs (the ones not floating)?

Comment: @FelipeAls - You declare your own margins immediately after the reset. I am aware of the critique of CSS resets but nevertheless I have not yet worked with a front-end developer who didn't curse after starting work w/o them.

Answer (score 5):

All paragraphs have a default margin: `p { margin: 1em 0; }` and a floated one is no different.

1. If you measure the margin between 2 paragraphs in your browser, you'll see that it isn't 2em (1em+1em) but only a total of 1em.
2. And this floated paragraph is different from the others while having the same default margins.

Why 1.? (Vertical) margins are said to be collapsed ([CSS2.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)). This is very natural while text is displayed (and HTML/CSS is about text mainly), not so natural when dealing with other types of content but browsers can't know this sort of thing...

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a **collapsed margin**.
>   (...)
>   Horizontal margins never collapse.

Why 2.? The difference is that vertical margins do not collapse for floated elements (same link as above, see the second note in green)

> **Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse**

The solution is then pretty obvious: when it comes to vertical margins, you must treat floated elements in a different way than those still in the normal flow of the document (at least you must consider if the values have to be modified or not). Here `.foo { margin-top: 0 }` or `.foo { margin: 0 }` (depends of the margin you want at the bottom of this floating paragraph)

Answer (score 2):

i think, when an Text Element, like `<p></p>` or something like `<h1></h1>` get out of DOM with **Float**, or special positioning like **position:absolute** or **position:fixed** get double top margin, this Rule is just about text elements, and not for div, or any other elements.

the solution is clear, just add **`margin-top:0`** to element and fix the problem.

Comment: Well observed, except the special case is having expected vertical margins and the normal case is having *collapsed margins*

Answer (score 0):

A `p` element gets a default style by the browser. They have default user agent stylesheets which load on every page even if the site never tells it to. Try using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or some other normalizing stylesheet to 'disable' default browser styles.

Default Chrome/chromium style for the `p` element:

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why it's rendered differently in one case (when it floats). I don't think normalize.css will avoid collapsing margins...

Comment: The sibling `p` element also has a `margin-top` from the browser, which pushes it down. The `float: right` will position it next to the sibling and add its own margin top as well (so it will have a margin top of 20px). A normalize will fix this, but the easiest thing is just adding `p { margin-top: 0 }`.

Comment: They all have a `margin-top` that pushes them down (by the exact same value), isn't it?

Comment: (If I understand your question correctly:) Yes, and the element that the float element is next to pushes the float element down as well.

Comment: Other paragraphs don't push a para that follows them but in this case it does: do you know *why* and how would normalize.css help here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, most browsers set `<p>`s to have margins on top. In fact, ALL of those `<p>`s in your codepen example have margins. If you're using Chrome, it's coming from the default browser styles:

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

To fix that, simply add the following extra CSS:

```
.foo {
    margin-top: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Fix what? What's broken or why is there a different behavior? Also no need to add `px` after a value of `0` (0 is unitless)